Cannot start npm run dev on Vite + Laravel 10 + PHP 8.3 + php:8.3.4-apache DockerImage
I'm using a small Dockerfile as the Laravel development environment:
FROM php:8.3.4-apache

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    unixodbc-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP basic extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo pdo_mysql

# Install Composer globally
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Clone your Laravel project from a Git repository
COPY . .

COPY web-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/web-default.conf

# Install project dependencies with Composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN composer install 
# Set file and folder permissions (adjust as needed)
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data storage bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage
# Enable Apache rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install npm -y
RUN npm install
# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5173

# Start the Apache server
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

And the docker-compose file:
version: '3'
services:
  www:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 5173:5173
    networks:
      - my-docker-network
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql-database:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - my-docker-network
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
networks:
  my-docker-network:

So the issue is that I want to avoid running npm run build everytime I want to see changes on my frontend. So for that reason I went into the Docker container terminal and run
npm run dev
This is what the terminal shows:
root@663ca79f2c46:/var/www/html# npm run dev

> dev
> vite

(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.

  VITE v4.5.2  ready in 694 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help

  LARAVEL v10.22.0  plugin v0.8.1

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost

But then when I go to the browser on localhost 3 errors:
GET http://localhost:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
GET http://localhost:5173/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
GET http://localhost:5173/resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 

The commands that I used for installing vite:
composer require laravel/jetstream
php artisan jetstream:install inertia

Any recomendation to the docker/docker-compose files would be appreciated. Please don't recommend me to use Laravel Sail as an answer, I've already tried it.
I tried changing the ports from 80 to 8000 and running npm run dev --host --port 5173 and also npm run dev --host --port 80 But didn't work. I'm also looking at the error (!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
Extra comment: When I run npm run build everything works perfectly fine.

Have you tried accessing it from inside the container? Use CURL inside your container to check your npm server is up and running.
